# Não utilizar o onItemClick

Tags: android-studio, android-adapter, android-recyclerview

Eu gostaria de utilizar o onLongItemClick do método .addOnItemTouchListener, mas somente ele. Não quero utilizar o onItemClick porque ele atrapalha uma outra forma que utilizo para clicar no item da lista (por meio do adapter, clico somente numa imagem ao invés do item inteiro na lista). Gostaria de saber se há alguma forma de retirar ou incapacitar o uso desse onItemClick no método. Ou então alguma forma de utilizar somente o onLongItemClick [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Apenas deixar a implementação do método em branco não soluciona o seu problema?

Comment: Não, é obrigatório ter esse método. Se houver alguma outra forma de utilizar somente o onLongItemClick seria muito bom tb